# how to check a checkbox in a page using mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mechanize

How can i check a check-box in a page using mechanize gem. **The check-box is not inside any form.** after checking the check-box I want to get a content of a div which will come from a ajax call.

I want to call the website(http://college-scholarships.findthebest.com/) and check the All check box so that i can get all the results.

Comment: We need more information, like an snippet of HTML to demonstrate what you're working with, plus some sample code showing what you've tried.

Comment: sure let me provide that and edit my question.

Comment: If the checkbox isn't part of a form, then checking it won't do anything.

Comment: You still haven't helped us help you. We need to see what you've tried, and a snippet of the HTML that demonstrates the problem. Don't rely on a link to a page as it tells us you didn't want to take the time to ask a good question. Also, link-rot will set in making it useless in the future.

Comment: @theTinMan I have not followed any link. i was tried to do it. But i have not found any way to do it. But yes it seems like what pguardiario is saying is correct.